# File encoding seems to break edited PHP file

Tags: character-encoding, ftp, phpstorm

I have a WordPress site hosted with BlueHost. When I FTP on to the server, edit a WordPress theme file and re-upload, I get a white screen with the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /home/challey3/public_html/wp-content/themes/challengers/page-invoice-payment.php
>   on line 1

The code is being downloaded directly to my hard drive and edited using PhpStorm, I've noticed then when I open the file in PhpStorm there is an additional blank line between each line of code, whereas the additional lines are not present when editing through Notepad.

The changes to the code were adding a jQuery snippet to the HTML and no modifications were made to the PHP itself. Undoing adding the snippet and re-uploading have the same effect, however, if I do a Git revert and re-upload the problem is resolved.

The only thing I can think is that the file is being encoded differently through PhpStorm/Windows and uploading it back to the server is somehow breaking things. The server is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Quite possibly it's about line ending used in that file + FTP server config. PhpStorm does not modify the file during transfer (upload or download).. so it must be server-side setting (or something else). No other ideas on why it happens .. but here is the ticket in PhpStorm's Issue Tracker -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9103

Comment: **P.S.** I have dealt with such "broken" sites myself (2 of them) .. and people who were working on them did not use PhpStorm for sure .. but they somehow managed to get such result. Some files had 4 empty lines between each line of code (heavy mix of PHP and HTML code) .. and code still worked fine.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, exact same problem from this end. Going in via FileZilla and changing to Binary acted as a workaround for this one. Feel free to add this as the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: So .. what line endings are in that file (you can see it in status bar area -- next to encoding.. or in `File | Line Separators`). Try using Unix ones (`LF`). Right now my assumption is that FTP server reacts on `CR` and trying to "fix" it...

Comment: It's currently set to CRLF, switching to LF also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm does not modify the file during transfer (upload or download).. so it must be server-side (FTP) setting.

As per my knowledge it's about line ending used in that file + specific FTP server config.

---

**My assumption** (based on personal experience working with 2 such already "broken" sites + info from other users who faced the same) is that **during upload** FTP server reacts on `CR` (used as line ending symbol -- `CRLF` is what Windows uses) and tries to "fix" it by replacing it by `LF`.

The FTP server may simply be doing it wrong -- instead of replacing whole `CRLF` it just does it on `CR` only.. so you may simply ending up with `LFLF` (2 line endings in Unix style -- 2nd one makes that extra empty line).

**If I'm correct** -- try converting that file in IDE to use Unix style `LF` as line separators first (either via Status Bar (next to encoding) or `File | Line Separators`).

---

In any case: here is the ticket in PhpStorm's Issue Tracker -- maybe one day they can offer some better solution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9103 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.