# Edit PHP file codification issue

Tags: php, ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a project developed with CodeIgniter. I've downloaded it to edit with PhpStorm, but when I open any file of the project the editor adds a white line after every line of code. Any changes I make, for example to remove white lines only, cause that when I upload it to production, pages return error 500, all files edited return error 500.

I guess it is a codification issue but I don't have idea how to solve it in PhpStorm.

I've tried changing the Code Style with "Adjust Code Settings" option but it made no change.

Comment: I have seen a similar description a few times (even faced it myself once). The conclusion that I have made is that It's your (S)FTP server config -- it  tries to convert the line endings (e.g. from Linux to Windows style) but fails to do so properly (possibly because they are already Windows one and it does not detect it).

Comment: Have a look at this similar question -- based on your description (_as far as I'm getting the issue_) it should have the same roots. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47175435/783119 If it's not -- you will have to provide the details, like: server OS, local OS, deployment type (FTP/SFTP/FTPS/etc), download the file using FileZilla (or another app) and then share the whole file (no copy-paste content, but the actual file with Google Drive/iCloud/OneDrive/Dropbox or alike file sharing). **P.S.**  The ticket on PhpStorm end: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9103

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments, I wil try and comeback with result, I use same FTP for different projects but in different server, and don't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes it was FTP settings. I was usin FTP instead SFTP.

Comment: So you have switched to SFTP from FTP (the same server settings) and it started to work? if yes -- great. Please post your solution as an answer -- it will help others in a similar situation and having an Accepted answer make this question more visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File encoding seems to break edited PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175435/file-encoding-seems-to-break-edited-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

the error was due to FTP settings, I was using FTP instead of SFTP, then downloading php files from linux (Almalinux 8, in this case) to windows changed files line ending, so when try to upload again, we get error 500.

thanks for help.